# Como utilizar o localStorage nesse caso?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3

Eu consegui fazer um código que altera a cor da minha navbar com HTML e JavaScript, porém quando a pessoa atualiza a página a cor da navbar volta a normal, como eu posso utilizar o localStorage para salvar esse dado, até o usuário trocar novamente a cor da navbar? Segue o código do botão que eu criei:

```html
<div class="container p-4">
  <h1>Selecione uma cor:</h1>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = 'blue'">Azul</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = 'green'">Verde</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-dark col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = 'black'">Preto</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = 'orange'">Laranja</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-secondary col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = 'grey'">Cinza</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" onclick="document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = 'red'">Vermelho</button>
</div>
```

A minha dúvida é, como eu salvo esses dados do button com o localStorage e como eu carrego esses dados do localStorage no meu sistema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de usar o atributo `onclick` em cada um dos botões, crie um *event handler* `onclick` em todos eles e coloque em cada um um dataset com o nome da cor. Por exemplo:

```
data-cor="blue"
```

Esse atributo será buscado no evento e salvo no localStorage. Quando você recarregar a página, basta verificar se o localStorage existe e aplicar a cor salva nele no navbar.

Os botões devem ficar desta forma abaixo. Repare no atributo `data-cor` em cada um:

```
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" data-cor="blue">Azul</button>
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" data-cor="green">Verde</button>
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-dark col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" data-cor="black">Preto</button>
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" data-cor="orange">Laranja</button>
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-secondary col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" data-cor="grey">Cinza</button>
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pt-4 mt-4" data-cor="red">Vermelho</button>
```

E o JavaScript ficará assim:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   // seleciona todos os botões pelo atributo "name"
   var bts = document.querySelectorAll("[name=button]");
   // percorre todos os botões
   for(var botao of bts){
      // cria o event handler
      botao.onclick = function(){
         // pega o valor do dataset
         var c = this.dataset.cor;
         // aplica no navbar
         document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = c;
         // salva a cor no LS
         localStorage.setItem("cor", c);
      }
   }

   // aqui verifica o localStorage
   var ls = localStorage.getItem("cor");
   if(ls){
      document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = ls;
   }

});
```

> **Obs.:** o script só vai funcionar se **apenas** esse botões possuem o `name` "button". Se tiver outro botão fora dessa coleção com o mesmo
>   `name` e ele for clicado, vai bugar o localStorage.

Comment: Sam, muito obrigado, você esclareceu totalmente minha dúvida! porém vou mais além, caso eu deseje fazer isso com uma div também, eu incluiria algo aqui: document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = c; ou eu teria que fazer de outro modo? para aplicar a cor na navbar e em uma div

Comment: Blz, amigo. Saiba como agradecer no [tour]. Abs!

Comment: Já dei o voto, se puder me ajudar com a dúvida que coloquei a cima, eu agradeço

Comment: Vc pode pegar pelo id da div, se ela tiver. Algo como: `document.getElementById('id da div').style.background = c;`

Comment: Entendi, mais eu colocaria a baixo document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = c;  ? no caso ficaria document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = c; document.getElementById('minhadiv').style.background = c;

Comment: Sim, é só colocar abaixo do outro.

Comment: Eu tentei ir para o chat porém o stack over flow, não permetiu, bom. eu coloquei dessa forma: document.getElementById('navbar').style.background = ls;
      document.getElementById('navbar-left').style.background = ls;            porém ele não ativa, pelo que constatei, mesmo retirando o navar em cima ele não ativa a cor na do lado, será que não está encontrando o ID?  minha section está assim                               <section class="nav-menu-left" id="navbar-left">

Comment: Tente pelo console. Vai lá e executa `document.getElementById('navbar-left').style.background = "blue"` para ver se altera a cor. Ou então tenta `backgroundColor` no lugar de `background`. Pode ser algum conflito.

Comment: é ele não setou a cor, pelo console também, creio que seja algum conflito, ou esse código só funciona com um background?

Comment: Vai no inspecionar elementos do navegador e veja se a propriedade background foi aplicada e está riscada. Se tiver riscada, tem alguma coisa (provavelmente no CSS) ignorando o background.

Comment: ele não tá ignorando, na verdade não está nem aplicando, existe outra técnica para utilizar sem ser com a ID?

Comment: Pela classe: `document.querySelector(".nav-menu-left")`

Comment: não sei se vai ler ou conseguir me ajudar, o código funcionou perfeitamente, porém hoje me surgiu uma dúvida é possível alterar o <meta name="theme-color" content="" /> através do javascript utilizando o mesmo botão?